# Is this FSA Transition Diagram correct?

Tags: state-machine, finite-automata, deterministic

I had this problem I had to solve where I have to design a transition diagram to accept a string A, where A is any string with a substring of 101 in any position over the set {0,1} `(RE of (1+0)*101(1+0)*)`. I solved it and designed the machine and drew it on an online tool but unfortunately the material I'm studying from does not have any written solution to this problem for me to check, so I wanted to check if my answer is correct here, since google gave me various answers none of which were like mine.

[image]

Now the idea here is that the diagram keeps going on forever, alternating between states until it encounters a consecutive input of 101, then it ends up in the final state q4, in which it's free to continue receiving whatever input until the end of the string. Is what I have done correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is q2 needed? I would just do a `q0->q0` transition for 0.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the string `1101`. It is valid, but your machine will end in state q1 and reject it.